# Magento multi store multi currency

Tags: magento

i have 2 store, 1 for USD 2 for CAD

my first store working fine, my 2nd store shows product value CAD when i send in paypal that time CAD value convert in USD, can you suggest me how to slove it i need when paypal goes its show CAD.

Comment: make CAD your default currency then

Answer (score 19):

The solution to this problem lies in [this Magento thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2623/P45/); here’s a summary for anyone struggling with this:

1. You need to set-up multiple websites, one for each currency (not just store views, complete websites)
2. Set ‘Catalog Price Scope’ to ‘Website’ in ***`System > Configuration > Catalog`***
3. Set the Base Currency of each website to its respective currency in ***`System > Configuration > Currency Setup`***
4. Set all your currency rates to ‘1.0’ in ***`System > Manage Currency Rates`***
5. Now you can set your product prices per store when editing a product, voila!

Comment: i have dome multiple store what you mean "complete websites", can you explain me. i am confuse

Comment: @JeetRoy It's a little late, but just for anyone else: Configuration > Manage Stores.  Then 'Create Website' for new currency, then 'Create Store' and select the new website, finally 'Create Store View' for the new store.

Comment: It's also work noting that after changing the catalog price scope, you need to change the 'Base Currency' for each website in System > Configure,  General > Currency Setup

Comment: Do we really need step 4: `Set all your currency rates to ‘1.0’ in System > Manage Currency Rates` But thanks for all the steps. Didn't knew you could have different base currencies. (Y)

Comment: Setting 3 should be before Setting 2.

Comment: I've edited the post and reversed steps 2 and 3 as noted by @Navarr. These 2 steps must be done in this order.

Comment: thanks so much for this. I hadn't done step 4 and have spent days trying to get to the bottom of it. Thanks again