# use multiple currencies in magento

Tags: magento, currency

how to manage multiple currencies in single setup and single site of Magento ?
I want to use Indian Rupees and Dollar in one site.

Any one has idea about this how to make it?

Comment: Did you try a search first? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9738660/2047249, http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/managing-currency, http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Comment: I want to use two currency in site, make option for user choice in which currency he/she want to do payment.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple ,i wonder why you didnt put a small effort on google .

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Comment: I already try this link and also implement in my code but it did not work for me.

Comment: You must show your code to us so that we may check the error or bug with that code.

Comment: Jo bhai no maja avti hoy ne to ans nahi apvano, baki biju kai na joye

Answer (score 0):

To setup Multiple currencies for magento store is very easy. To do so, just follow below steps:

1. Login to admin panel of your website.
2. Go to System --> Configuration, then select Currency Setup from General tab.

   ```
   Then select values for Base currency, Default display currency and Allowed currencies and Save Config button.
   ```

   Note: Press Control key of key board while selecting multiple options from Allowed Currencies section.

   Magento still does not know about currency rates for newly selected currencies. To let magento know about currency interchange rates, follow step #3.
3. Go to System --> Manage Currency --> Rates.

   ```
   Just click on Import button on top right side. Now click on Save Currency Rates button.
   ```

   That's all.. refresh magento cache and you are done.